# Do std::async and std::future use mutexes and a condition variable under the hood?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've been lead to believe that using std::async with the returned future is basically just a simplified way of using mutexes, where the actual handling of the new std::thread and the locking/unlocking of the mutex is abstracted away by the async function and the future.

I'm fairly new to multi-threading concepts - is this the case? Am I understanding something incorrectly?

Edit: I left out that this abstraction would obviously make use of an std::condition_variable

Comment: It’s pretty correct, async and future can be implemented in c++. I don’t think it’s easy with just a mutex, but it’s trivial with condition_variable and a mutex.

Comment: @Dani thanks - I added that to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe.

It's up to the implementer. They *can* do it with `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`, or with the underlying components with which they implemented those, or with some other scheme.

The standard prescribes the observable behaviour, not the implementation.

Comment: Probably the answer I was looking for. At least I (hopefully) understand what's going on. Appreciate the help